# share_item extended permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

With Graph API 2.0, things get quite a bit more complicated for developers.

I have a WordPress plugin which automatically posts update to my Facebook Pages when a new post is published. Every WordPress site uses a different Facebook App to communicate with Facebook's API in publishing posts to their respective Facebook Pages.

Older apps that has been setup already have all the permissions required setup and authenticated so they all work fine.

The newer one that I'm about to setup is different because publishing require approval before I can request that particular permission I want.

I already got my app approved with `publish_actions` and `manage_pages` permission. Unfortunately, the plugin doesn't work and this error is thrown by Facebook.

> (#100) Required extended permission: share_item

There isn't any `share_item` permission listed for me to submit for approval. What can I do to fix this problem?

New [Graph API 2.0 Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0) doesn't mention anything about `share_item` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a bug. Either the error message is wrong or you should be able to submit share_item for review.

Please see if a bug have been reported at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs and if it doesn't please file one.

**Update:** After looking into it it seems that the error message is wrong. As long as you have publish_actions you are fine.

Comment: Do you mean bug in the plugin or on the Facebook's side? The error message comes from `catch(FacebookApiException $e)` and `$e->getMessage()`.

Comment: For me it sounds like a bug on Facebook's side.

Comment: Ok, I checked an the error message is just wrong. You just need publish_actions. So make sure that the user have granted that permission before you call the API and everything should be fine

Comment: Thanks. Seems like the plugin was written to request the permission `publish_stream` which is replaced by `publish_actions` now. After I fixed that, everything seems to work fine now. Facebook Apps permission review process is so much hassle now.